# Textarea do not show in nested svg

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, svg

I embed textarea in foreignObject in a nested svg, but the textarea cant show in my latest chrome. Can some one help me? Thanks in advance!

```css
textarea {
  resize: none;
  width: 128px;
  height: 20px;
  font-size: 13px;
}
```

```html
<svg width="1000" height="200">
  <foreignObject x="35" y="10" width="130" height="22">
    <input type="text" maxlength="20" style="width: 128px;">
  </foreignObject>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="node" x="170" y="0">
    <foreignObject x="20" y="0" width="143" height="32">
      <p>text not show after input charactors below</p>
      <textarea contenteditable>112233112233112233112233112233112233</textarea>
      <div>123</div>
    </foreignObject>
  </svg>
```

Comment: because you're foreignobject width limits it width="143" as well as you will have to increase the height for the text area to be visible.

Answer (score 2):

In the following line of code you've limited your **foreignObject** container size to `143px vs 32px` and thus your `paragraph tag` as well as the `text area` **gets cut off**.

```
<foreignObject x="20" y="0" width="143" height="32">
```

If you **modify/increase** the size, they'll show up:

```
<foreignObject x="20" y="0" width="100%" height="200">
```

```css
textarea {
  resize: none;
  width: 128px !important;
  height: 20px !important;
  font-size: 13px;
}
```

```html
<svg width="1000" height="200">
  <foreignObject x="35" y="10" width="132" height="22">
    <input type="text" maxlength="20" style="width: 128px;">
  </foreignObject>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="node" x="170" y="0">
    <foreignObject x="20" y="0" width="100%" height="200">
      <p>text not show after input charactors below</p>
      <textarea contenteditable>1111111111111111111111111111114322432</textarea>
      <div>123</div>
    </foreignObject>
  </svg>
  </svg>
```

Comment: @somethin Check the code snippet I posted and compare it against your code, check your textarea's height, your foreignObject's width and height as well.

Comment: Thank, but I want the textarea height to be fixed 20px, and let the text inside it flows as it's in normal html

Comment: Then just keep the height of textarea as 20px in CSS. :)

Comment: @somethin Updated my answer with textarea height 20px.

Comment: @somethin Just noticed, it seems like a bug in chrome. Even if I remove that long text from textarea, it appears at 20px height, but if I type something and it overflows the textarea, then it disappears. Doesn't happen in firefox though.

Comment: Thanks for your research. Firefox works well for me too. Another thing I noticed is that if I move the left <input> into the textarea's foreignobject and elimite the maxlength, then I type, the <input> is still show, but its content inside disappears. That's very strange.

Comment: I think I understand what the problem might be, its the other svg nested within and chrome isnt supporting it well.

Comment: @somethin Try this on chrome

Comment: Thank you @Highdef,  it works great, but I am using the outer <svg> to bind events like zoom and mousewheel, and the inner svg to control its position because its one of the many children of the outer svg. and the inner svg has many elments not only the textarea.

Comment: @somethin I don't think firefox will be an issue but it is weird why chrome is messing it up like that. When the svg is nested within it won't function as intended.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161707/discussion-between-highdef-and-somethin).